# AttributeError occurs while running ResNet50 using Keras on Pycharm

Tags: machine-learning, keras, pycharm, image-recognition, resnet

I was using PyCharm and imported ResNet50 for image recognition of a sample image. When I run the code , the following error occured.

I was learning using an online code which needed to be completed by learners. I configured PyCharm and installed required packages that were recommended. During learning image recognition using ResNet50 , while running the code I ended up with following error. Should I custom install ResNet50 on pycharm for this to work? The instructor said the IDE will auto download ResNet50 during execution of code. Attaching python code below.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications import resnet50

model = resnet50.ResNet50

img = image.load_img("bay.jpg", target_size=(224, 224))

x = image.img_to_array(img)

x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

x = resnet50.preprocess_input(x)

predictions = model.predict(x)

predicted_classes = resnet50.decode_predictions(predictions, top=9)

print("This is an image of:")

for imagenet_id, name, likelihood in predicted_classes[0]:
    print(" - {}: {:2f} likelihood".format(name, likelihood))
```

This is the resultant error that I am getting during execution.

```
File "/home/warlock/Downloads/Ex_Files_Building_Deep_Learning_Apps/
Exercise Files/05/image_recognition.py", line 21, in <module>
    predictions = model.predict(x)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because `ResNet50` is a fonction so you need to implement it like a fonction :

```
model = resnet50.ResNet50()
```

In order to have a resnet50 model with all default parameters